# Ubuntu 20.04 mate strange behavior after suspend

Tags: 20.04, apache2, suspend, ubuntu-mate

I moved not long time ago to Ubuntu 20.04, and installed mate.
After installing apache2, I have a very strange behavior after suspending the system:

1. I am not asked to introduce password in order to restore system
2. The second display is black. I need to enter **Display**, deactivate the second monitor, and then activate it again in order to have it working.
3. Scrolling browser with mouse wheel is extremely slow.

I imagine more information is needed, but have no idea what else to mention.
Does anybody know what should I do?